# Good backup solution for Xen virtual machines?

Tags: backup, disaster-recovery, monitoring

we are looking for a backup solution for our xen servers that meets the following requirements:

1. makes backups while machines are running
2. has easy to use disaster recovery without depending on complex infrastructure in case of a disaster
3. can backup all kinds of linux and windows machines
4. sends some kind of message if something is not working. We dont want to monitor everything manually

We tried Acronis Backup & Recovery 10 virtual edition but it is not compatible with linux vms. Bacula does not seem to have good disaster recovery, as far as we know.

My question: What are good backup solutions for our requirements?

Thanks advance for your answers.

Cheers

Arne

Comment: Very late to respond back but my company ended up going with Xackup: http://www.xenserver-backup.com/. Works great, easy to use and pretty cheap compared to some of the other options recommended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally like [Commvault's](http://www.commvault.com/solutions-virtualization.html) stuff, but I use it on ESXi not Xen, thoughh Xen is supported.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://www.markround.com/archives/61-Xenserver-snapshot-and-template-based-backup-script.html/

The only dislike I had about it is it backs up all running VM's. I'm in the process of looking for a tool/script that will allow me to backup the VM's running on a host so then I can schedule backups for VM's based on the host they reside on.

Comment: Please don't only leave link answers. Links can become dead.